# Seeking alternative to Windows Help viewer

Tags: help-files

MicroSotft discontinued the Help Viewer with Vista.  It is still available as a download, but I am having problems installing that, so while I try to solve them I thought that I woudl ask if anyone knows of an alternative .HLP viewer .....

Comment: I wonder if one of the HLP-to-RTF converters could be helpful to you?  Once converted to RTF, you should be able to read it in well-known word processors such as OpenOffice Writer, Microsoft Word, WordPerfect, etc. (**be careful** though, because some of this stuff **stinks** of being **SpyWare**!):  http://www.google.com/search?q=hlp-to-rtf

Comment: What install problems are you having with the old help viewer?

Comment: OP's note: Nowadays, such questions should be asked at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Help Explorer Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Help-Explorer-Viewer/3000-6675_4-10666661.html). It is from the year 2007 and discontinued by the developer but still available to download via the link.

PS: If the answer comes to late for you, it might help someone else.

Comment: Works but appears to be limited in how many topics it can list (I tried it with old winapi reference, it only got halfway)